# Почему открывается новое окно, а не дерево папок в Sublime Text при нажатии на Open Folder

Tags: sublime-text-3

Жму в Sublime Text 3 на Open Folder... открывается просто пустое окно, **не вкладка**. Как решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А это не баг, это фича. Если у вас уже открыто окно с какой-то структурой папок, и при этом вы пробуете открыть еще одну папку - Sublime Text должен сохранить и вашу текущую структуру папок, и показать новую. Поэтому он открывает новое окно для новой структуры папок.

Возможно вы хотите добавить папку к уже открытой? Тогда вам нужен пункт `Project` → `Add folder to Project`.

P.S. Возможно, также, что у вас при открытии папки не видно дерево папок слева? Тогда, вероятно, у вас скрыта эта панель. Показать можно через `View` → `Side Bar` → `Show Side Bar`.

Comment: Да, дерево папок было скрыто. Спасибо!

Comment: я ненавижу этот саблайм за такие моменты!